# Trying to get rid of .html from URLs and receiving 403 error when going to a page with a sub folder

Tags: html, .htaccess, directory, cpanel, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to get rid of .html from the URLs on a site. However, I'm getting 403 errors on pages which have a sub-folder with the same name. ie sitename/solutions.html also has a subfolder which has pages in it such as solution1.html,solution2.html etc...

Pages without subfolders ie. about.html works fine and goes to sitename/about

I am using the code below to get rid of the extension .html for the URLs on a site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

I think the rule has changed it so that its trying to get access to the actual folder ie. solutions and I want it to go to solutions.html but without the .html extension.

Do I need to change my folder names so they are different and don't bring up a 403. Won't that change the URLs though? I want them to be in that folder.

Any help appreciated